# Find a path that is less than n pixels far from mouse position in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to improve selecting lines on chart by increasing margin of error for click by few pixels. I found very good solution that is using Voronoi algorithm:

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/8033015

This is very smart approach, but has no use in my case. I just want to implement some kind of override function for click that spreads the range of click to few nearest pixels.

Answer (score 2):

One simple solution is to create a double of your path, with a transparent bigger stroke, and listen to this double's event.

Here is a non d3 proof-of concept:

```css
.bg {
  stroke: transparent;
  stroke-width: 25px;
  fill: none;
}
.fg {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  fill: none;
}
.bg:hover + .fg {
  stroke: red;
}
.fg:hover {
  stroke: green;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
  <path class="bg" d="M 100 100 L 300 100 L 200 300 z"></path>
  <path class="fg" d="M 100 100 L 300 100 L 200 300 z"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Yes, I also considered this approach, but the problem appears when the paths (the visible ones) are too close to each other. E.g. one of them is 2px far from the point of click and second is 8px far. The second will be clicked because it covers the first one. Btw. I found another solution for now. I'm listening for click event on whole svg, getting mouse position from event and looking for elements that are paths in the nearest neighborhood of this mouse position.

Comment: @mankers all solutions will come with this exact problem. If two pathes are as close as the mouse coords, then you have to choose. With above solution, this can be controlled through the place in svg tree your nodes are.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but I want to simply find the one that is closer, so I think that the approach to check all neighbors, starting from the exact point of click, then iterate through the points laying on the circle with radius 1px. No success - increase radius and keep checking. We can then set maximum radius and when we achieve it we stop with no success. I know that it's more time consuming, but the maximum radius that I'm interested in is not going to be bigger than 3px.

Comment: I've just known further requirements for my task and it seems that my solution is too slow now. I also have to handle mouse move event, so it's not good idea to do these calculations after every mouse movement. Another reason to accept your approach is quite small prescision (3px), so the situations like I described in previous comment (paths overlapping) should be very rare and unnoticeable to user. Thanks a lot for your help! +1